# $S^1\times S^1$ diffeomoprhic to torus of revolution.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am searching for an diffeomorphism between $$S^1\times S^1$$ and the torus of revolution $$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|z^2+(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2=r^2\}.$$

I know it's true, I am just looking for an explicit formula. Thanks a lot!

I managed to wirte down a diffeomoprhism between $$S^1\times S^1$$ and $$\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$$ but I am stuck with this one.

Comment: It's better that you accept the answer. This avoid others trying give an answer. :)

Comment: Could you show me which diffeomorphism found between $S^1 \times S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrize the torus of revolution by thinking of it literally as a circle rotated in a circle. The angle of the circle being revolved will be $\phi$ and the angle of the revolutionary circle will be $\theta$. So for a major radius of $R$, the revolutionary circle is $(R\cos\theta,R\sin\theta,0)$. For any $\theta$, and if the minor radius is $r$, the circle being revolved is $r(\cos\phi,0,\sin\phi)$, except rotated by an angle of $\theta$ in order to lie in the plane spanned by $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$ and the $z$-axis.

Thus:
$$f(\theta,\phi) = R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0) + r(\cos\phi\cos\theta,\cos\phi\sin\theta,\sin\phi).$$
This is a local diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto the torus of revolution which is $(2\pi)\mathbb{Z}^2$-periodic, so it descends to a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$. (There are still details to check, but I'll leave them to you.)